# Is there a working example of using WebDAV for querying Exchange server for calendar items?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, webdav

I have tried to hack together a small test project, but it fails with "400 Bad Request" so I'm pretty sure I have done something very basic wrong, but the examples I've found are all in the form of questions, only showing minor pieces of the puzzle, such as a request XML for public folders or whatnot.

Is there a complete example somewhere where I can just put in my username and servername and it would list the calendar items in my calendar?

This is for C# 3.0/4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer, which was perhaps overkill for another SO question. ^^ For your comfort I put the link right here. [A query example on the bottom of my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072565/acessing-calendar-of-user-email-address-using-java/13078355#13078355). It might help you, though I didn't put the whole code into it, because it isn't public domain. The code example was from a Java program.

If everything was correct with your code, then the response from the Exchange Server will return you an XML String, which contains Calendar or Appointment Items for further processing.

Best regards,

Semo